# Boostrap Modal not working on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have readed a lot of blogs and articles about showing MVC partial views using Boostrap modals. It seems that I have exactly what I'm seen on the material consulted but still it doesn't show the modal. I just need to show the partial view with the Album details in a modal. The controller is working fine when I load the URL through the browser.

This is the **Index HTML** code where the modal is shown:

```
<tbody>
            @foreach( var album in Model.Albums)
            {
                <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#albumModal" data-url="@Url.Action("Album", new { id = album.Id })">
                    <td>@album.Title</td>
                    <td>@album.Artist</td>
                    <td>@album.Genre</td>
                    <td>@album.Year</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

**Partial View**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="albumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="albumModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="albumModalLabel">Album Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Album<input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" /></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Artist <input class="form-control" type="text" id="artist" /></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Genre <input class="form-control" type="text" id="genre" /></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Year <input class="form-control" type="text" id="year" /></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Track</th>
                                <th>Song Title</th>
                                <th>Length</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="tracks"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HomeController**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Album(int? id)
{
    if (id == null) return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    var albumInfo = _service.GetAlbumInfo((int) id);
    if (albumInfo == null) return HttpNotFound();
    return PartialView("_Album", albumInfo);
}
```

**Script**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.list-element').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var $buttonClicked = $(this);
            var url = $buttonClicked.attr('data-url');


            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#albumContainer').html(data);

                $('#albumModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
```

In almost all of the SO questions counsulted, they wasn't using data-target but I am. What do I need to modify to achieve that the modal shows?

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Do you want to open the model when you click on a table row and populate the form controls with the values from the associated table cells in that row (in which case, calling a controller method is not necessary)

Comment: Have you included the relevant javascript references for Bootstrap?

Comment: Stephen. Basically, I want that every row of the table works as a link to show the modal. That's why I have all of the modal related code in the <tr> definition. I have to call the controller due to the album has more information that I have to show. For example, a list of tracks. Brendan, I have registered all of the bundles in RegisterBundles. Is that what you mean?

Comment: But your modal form is not binding to anything. The partial needs @model Album` and your controller method needs to initialize a model based on the `album.Id` and pass it to the partial, and in the partial bind to it using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods - e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)` etc.

Comment: The you need to handle the `.click()` event of each row to call the method that returns that partial and add it to the DOM (although it would be more efficient to include one hidden modal in the view, and return json containing the data, and then just update the form controls etc and show the modal

Comment: Stephen, I just added my controller code and the script that I had for doing what you are saying. Of course, adding id="list-element" to every <tr> and having a div with id="albumContainer"  but it doens't work either. I thought It wasn't necessary in firts place mapping what the controller return. At least, I should get an empty modal. Right?

Comment: @javier_el_bene, I cant see any element with `class="list-element"` in your view. But if you give each `<tr>` that class name and use `var url = $(this).data('url');` then your script will work fine (assuming the main view contains an element with `id="albumContainer"` in which to load the partial.

Answer (score 0):

VIEW

```
@model ShowModal

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#albumModal" data-url="@Url.Action("Album", new { id = album.Id })">
            <td>@album.Title</td>
            <td>@album.Artist</td>
            <td>@album.Genre</td>
            <td>@album.Year</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="albumModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="albumModal">  
     @Html.Partial("_albumPartial", Model)
 </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Album(int? id)
{
    ShowModal modal = new ShowModal();   
    var albumInfo = _service.GetAlbumInfo((int) id);

    modal.Info1 = albumInfo.Info1;//and other fields
    return PartialView("_albumPartial", modal);
}
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#albumModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            var url = button.data('url') // or button.attr("data-url") or get here just the id and create the URL here


            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#albumModal').html(data);
                $('#albumModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```